# HTML mobile app with offline storage only

Tags: html, cordova, kendo-ui

I need to create a mobile app based on HTML5 that would run on iOS devices (iPhone, iPad) and Android phones and tablets.

The app is about storing grocery items.  I will have categories and items along with images for items.  All this data will be generated by the user of the app.
The app will not require any network connectivity and just need to store the data offline.

I am thinking I can use the following technologies for this app and would appreciate some guidance:
1) PhoneGap - I think I will be able to use the Storage API provided.
Will this allow me to create a SQLite database on the device and the ability to perform CRUD operations on the data?
Also, is there a space limit?  I was looking at LocalStorage, WebSQL.... really confused about storage.

2) KendoUI Controls for Mobile - use this to create the layout.  The question here is that can KendoUI be used with PhoneGap for offline storage.  All examples of KendoUI seem to work with data from network services.... not much guidance around offline storage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All Kendo widgets can operate with remote and local data. To read and write data at LocalStorage or WebSQL data base you should create a custom transport. Check the following examples:

1. [KendoUI and WebSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496254/how-to-query-a-local-websql-db-with-kendo-ui)
2. [KendoUI and LocalStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980444/caching-a-kendo-ui-datasource-object-using-localstorage/13753701#13753701)