# How to query a local websql DB with Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Forgive me if this question is too broad for SO but I'm struggling to find any examples of what I need and thought someone may be able to point me in the right direction.

I'm just starting out with Kendo UI mobile and am trying to find a tutorial or any example code for creating/querying a local client side websql database within kendo ui mobile. There is nothing in the docs...

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a custom transport for the Kendo DataSource. For example in [transport.read](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportread-objectstringfunction) you can perform a query to your websql database and return the result:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
   transport: {
      read: function(options) {

        db.transaction(function(tx) {

          tx.executeSql('SELECT * from my_table', [], function(tx, result) {

             var data = [];
             // copy the rows to a regular array
             for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                data[i] = result.rows.item(i);
             }

             options.success(data); // return the data back to the data source
          });
        });
      }
   }
});
```

Here is a full CRUD demo: http://jsbin.com/azukin/4/edit

Answer (score 1):

With JayData you can do it with just a few lines of code and it will support not only websql but indexeddb too
http://jaydata.org/blog/jaydata-kendo-ui-awesomeness

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com), that can store data in WebSQL.
There is [kendo-pouchdb](https://github.com/terikon/kendo-pouchdb) adapter that connects PouchDB database with Kendo UI or Kendo Mobile widgets.

Here's [demo](http://terikon.github.io/kendo-pouchdb/demo/kendo-pouchdb-grid.html) of Kendo Grid that read and updates data in PouchDB.

P.S. I'm the author of kendo-pouchdb.